# Heroku - How to encrypt the database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Is there a recommended way for encrypting sensitive data on Heroku in a way that would satisfy the a large company's IT security compliance requirements?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? if yes, you should put the answer here as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has [pgcrypto](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html) to encrypt your data. The PGP encryption functions will do the job for you, just let Heroku use these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am leaning toward app-level management of encrypted data in the DB. i.e. each user has its own public/private key stored in a separate DB on a separate server (maybe the app server itself).